# Create a GeoTIFF from a GeoTIFF using only one of it's values

Tags: python, gdal, polygon, geotiff-tiff

Does anyone have a method for extracting pixels from a GeoTIFF that are of a particular value. So for example if a band had values from 0 to 10 and I wanted to make an image just using the zero values and to leave the other pixel values as unknown.

My GeoTIFF is 19 GB large so I'd prefer to avoid using QGIS. I've already tried GRASS and it would freeze on me. I would prefer a solution that can use the GDAL tools but Python would be good too.

My eventual goal is to extract the polygons that surround regions of interest using the monochrome image generated from the above.

Comment: Have you tried [raster calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html#gdalrastercalculator)?

Comment: @BERA I have but it was freezing.

Comment: Or have you tried gdal_calc python script https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html?

Comment: @user30184 no I haven't. I will try that right now.

Comment: It will be faster to test with an image that is smaller than 19 GB. You can find the limits later and with so big image you will want to use a few creation options as well, at least tiled=yes and some compression method.

Comment: @user30184 wrt tiles, were you refering to breaking up the large image with gdal2tiles.py, using gdal_calc.py on each tile and then running gdal_retile,py to reassemble it?

Comment: No, I was referring to internal organization of TIFF file so that data is written as rectangular blocks. The other option is to write data as stripes which are sets of one ore more rows of pixels. It is much more memory friendly to access data from random small area with the tiled organization. GDAL controls that with the creation option `-tiled=yes` https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not tried this but I think the example in the [gdal_calc](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html) manual page

```
gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A*(A>0)" --NoDataValue=0
```

could be changed to

```
gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A*(A==1)" --NoDataValue=0
```

should work to extract value 1.

Comment: I'm running it, we'll see if I get the desired result.

Comment: That worked for what I needed. In particular I used --calc="A==0" since I only wanted to extract the border around the data.

Answer (score 1):

this is one way to do what you want using GDAL and NUMPY.

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

rasterFile = 'C:/Users/pepito/yourinputraster.tif'
in_ds = gdal.Open(rasterFile)
in_band = in_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
in_data = in_band.ReadAsArray()

#this is the line that makes the reclass
reclas = np.where(in_data == 0, 1, 0)

# output as TIFF
gtiff_driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
out_ds = gtiff_driver.Create('C:/Users/pepito/youroutputraster.tif',in_band.XSize, in_band.YSize, 1, in_band.DataType)
out_ds.SetProjection(in_ds.GetProjection())
out_ds.SetGeoTransform(in_ds.GetGeoTransform())
out_band = out_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
out_band.SetNoDataValue(0)
out_band.WriteArray(reclas)
out_ds.FlushCache()
```

However if your raster is 19GB you will probably have to process it in chunks.